# T-SQL - compare column values and column names

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to get the values from a small table, that are not present as columns in an existing table.

Here is some code I tried in SQL Server 2012:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestValues](
    [IdValue] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestColumns](
    [DateHour] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [test1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [test2] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestValues] ([Code])
VALUES
    (N'test1')
    , (N'test2')
    , (N'test3')
;
GO
SELECT
    v.[Code]
    , c.[name]
FROM
    [dbo].[TestValues] AS v
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [sys].[columns] AS c ON v.[Code] = c.[name]
WHERE
    (c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestColumns]'))
    AND (c.[column_id] > 1)
;
WITH
cteColumns AS (
    SELECT
        c.[name]
    FROM
        [sys].[columns] AS c
    WHERE
        (c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestColumns]'))
        AND (c.[column_id] > 1)
)
SELECT
    v.[Code]
    , c.[name]
FROM
    [dbo].[TestValues] AS v
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteColumns AS c ON v.[Code] = c.[name]
;
GO
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```

In my opinion the two selects should have the same output. Can someone offer an explanation please?

`TestValues` is a table receiving data. `TestColumns` is a table that was created, when the project was started, by persisting a `PIVOT` query. Recently the process inserting into `TestValues` received some new data. I tried to get the new values using the first query and I was surprised when the result didn't show anything new.

Edit 1: Thank you dean for the answer, it sounds like a good explanation. Do you have any official page describing the behaviours of unpreserved tables? I did a quick google search and all I got was links towards Oracle. (added as an edit because I do not have enough reputation points to comment)

Comment: With OUTER joins, specifying columns from unpreserved table in WHERE condition discards all rows where there is no match, effectively transforming the OUTER into an INNER join.

Comment: as an add-on to dean's comment, you could move the `c.` limits to the JOIN itself as in `LEFT OUTER JOIN [sys].[columns] AS c ON v.[Code] = c.[name]
AND
    (c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestColumns]'))
    AND (c.[column_id] > 1)`